# Managed and Unmanaged dlls retrieval during the execution flow

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I have a third-party managed dll, calling for another unmanaged one. C# code calling it working fine on my machine in debug, not on the server I put it in.

Seems this is due to the installed versions on the server different from my machine. However wondering how the dll retrieval flow (managed/unmanaged) works.

Here is what I could understand so far:

**Managed dll**

1. RunTime looking in the ./ (most likely bin) folder first
2. If not found, checking the GAC (when is the dll installed there?)

**Unmanaged dll**

1. Could be called with an absolute path in the managed dll, in that case should be installed there.
2. If not, fallback will be the registry path, in that case would be picked up from there.

Is the above correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Unmanaged DLL search order follows these rules: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

In short:

- The directory from which the application loaded.
- The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
- The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
- The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
- The current directory.
- The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.